# Elementary bound theorem of a monic real polynomial

Tags: polynomials, roots

An elementary bound theorem on the roots of a real monic polynomial states that $$M := \operatorname{max} (1, |a_0| + \cdots + |a_{n-1}|) := \operatorname{max} (1, B)$$ is an upper and lower ($-M$) bound for the polynomial's roots. The proofs I know are either ugly (using synthetic substitution), or overkill ("follows from (a corollary of) Rouche's theorem").

To show the case when $M=1$ is easy. I struggle to find a nice, elementary proof when $M=B$. Searching MSE's database (as well as googling), I couldn't find one.

Comment: Gotcha!  Can you give references to the proofs you mentioned?  Preferably online?  Nice question, +1!  Thanks!

Comment: @RobertLewis: Example for [Synthetic Subsitition](http://mathweb.scranton.edu/monks/courses/ProblemSolving/POLYTHEOREMS.pdf); for the approach using Rouche's Theorem, see, eg, [here](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Properties_of_polynomial_roots) - but there are related questions on MSE too using it.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $|x|\ge1$, we have
$$
|a_0+a_1x+\cdots+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}| < |a_0| + |a_1| |x| + \cdots + |a_{n-1}| |x|^{n-1} \le B|x|^{n-1}.
$$
Therefore when $|x|>B$ as well,
$$
|a_0+a_1x+\cdots+a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + x^n| > |x|^n - B|x|^{n-1} > 0,
$$
and so the polynomial can't vanish.

Comment: Very nice indeed, sir!  Got my vote!

Comment: Feeling dumb now, but thanks! (In last line, first should probably be $\ge$, not >).

Answer (score 1):

Let $\alpha$ be a root of the polynomial $p(x)=x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\dots+a_1x+a_0$, by definition, we have:
$$\alpha^n=-(a_{n-1}\alpha^{n-1}+\dots+a_1\alpha+a_0)$$
so we have:
$$\lvert \alpha\rvert^n =\lvert a_{n-1}\alpha^{n-1} +\dots+ a_1\alpha+ a_0\rvert $$
Now if  $\lvert\alpha\rvert>B$, $\lvert \alpha\rvert^n >B^n$. However, if $B\ge 1$, we have:
\begin{align*}
\lvert a_{n-1}\alpha^{n-1} +\dots+ a_1\alpha+ a_0\rvert
&\le\lvert a_{n-1}\rvert\lvert\alpha^{n-1}\rvert+\dots+\lvert a_1\rvert\lvert\alpha\rvert + \lvert a_0\rvert \\
&\le (\lvert a_{n-1}\rvert\lvert B^{n-1}\rvert+\dots+\lvert a_1\rvert\lvert B \rvert + \lvert a_0\rvert \\
&\le (\lvert a_{n-1}\rvert+\dots+\lvert a_1\rvert+\lvert a_0\rvert)B^{n-1}=B^n
\end{align*}
Thus, $\lvert \alpha\rvert^n$ should be both $>B^n$ and $\le B^n$. Contradiction.

Comment: Nice! Thanks.      .